# Squid: Connection reset by peer (TLS code: SQUID_ERR_SSL_HANDSHAKE)

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy, squid

```
Failed to establish a secure connection to *ip-address*
```

The system returned:

```
(104) Connection reset by peer (TLS code: SQUID_ERR_SSL_HANDSHAKE)

Handshake with SSL server failed: [No Error]
```

This proxy and the remote host failed to negotiate a mutually acceptable security settings for handling your request. It is possible that the remote host does not support secure connections, or the proxy is not satisfied with the host security credentials.

any got an idea on how to fix this? Im unabe to access website behind the squid proxy.

Comment: Unfortunately it is impossible to say why the server reset the connection. It might be because of no shared ciphers or maybe because a client certificate is expected or maybe other things. Because of this it is also impossible to provide any recommendations how to fix this. If you would provide the actual domain in question one might have a closer look though.

Comment: Based on [the SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=sts1.statssa.gov.za) the site looks pretty ok, except for insisting on the obsolete RSA key exchange (i.e. no forward secrecy). The latter might be a problem depending on your (unknown) setup of the squid proxy. Does this problem affect only this specific web site or arbitrary ones?

Comment: It's only this website. Other ones are working fine.

Comment: When I run: Curl website.url  - vki

Comment: I get the following error :SSL certificate verify results: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continue anyway.   It then fails